# Appearance Application Menu Doesn't Appear in Gnome-Tweaks

Tags: gnome, appearance

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 and i want to customize my gnome using tweaks, but when i want to change application theme, the "Applications" menu doesn't exist in tweaks. can someone help me? thank you

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit] your question to indicate what change you want to make to your DE.  GNOME 40 is a different animal to that which existed previously but there are still things you can do to change things.

Answer (score 1):

In Tweaks 42.beta that comes with Ubuntu 22.04, you are now looking for Legacy applications" to set and change GTK2 and GTK3 themes. GTK4 applications that use libadwaita cannot anymore be themed. No GTK4 application is included yet in a default Ubuntu install. For all Gnome utilities that were already ported, Ubuntu for now kept a previous version.